# C Optimization of Function

Tags: c, optimization

I have a function that looks about like so, constants a1-e8 (double precision floats) are in the code let's say either hardcoded or as #defined. The function accepts doubles within the range of -1.0 to 1.0 and needs to be split in quarters as shown.

Are there any other code optimizations I can make to increase runtime performance before assembly language optimization? I tried making an x2 to hold x*x and made the e constants multiply by x2*x2 but it actually slowed down performance. I also tried seeing if I could cast a copy of x as an integer and use a switch statement but it also slowed down performance.

```
double operation(double x) {
    if (x <= -0.75 && x >= -1.0) {
        return a1 + b1*x + c1*x*x + d1*x*x*x + e1*x*x*x*x;
    }
    else if (x <= -0.5) {
        return a2 + b2*x - c2*x*x - d2*x*x*x - e2*x*x*x*x;
    }
    else if (x <= -0.25) {
        return a3 - b3*x - c3*x*x - d3*x*x*x - e3*x*x*x*x;
    }
    else if (x <= 0.0) {
        return a4 - b4*x - c4*x*x - d4*x*x*x + e4*x*x*x*x;
    }
    else if (x <= 0.25) {
        return a5 + b5*x - c5*x*x + d5*x*x*x + e5*x*x*x*x;
    }
    else if (x <= 0.5) {
        return a6 + b6*x - c6*x*x + d6*x*x*x - e6*x*x*x*x;
    }
    else if (x <= 0.75) {
        return a7 - b7*x - c7*x*x + d7*x*x*x - e7*x*x*x*x;
    }
    else if (x <= 1.0) {
        return a8 - b8*x + c8*x*x - d8*x*x*x + f8*x*x*x*x;
    }
    return 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202928/discussion-on-question-by-john-ernest-c-optimization-of-function).

Comment: If you like any of the answer, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any other code optimizations I can make to increase runtime performance before assembly language optimization?

Rearranging the comparisons so that you're basically doing a binary search for the right case rather than a linear one speeds things up quite a bit:

```
double op2(double x) {
    if (x <= 0) {
        if (x <= -0.5) {
            if (x <= -0.75 && x >= -1.0) {
                return a1 + b1*x + c1*x*x + d1*x*x*x + e1*x*x*x*x;
            }
            return a2 + b2*x - c2*x*x - d2*x*x*x - e2*x*x*x*x;
        }
        else {
            if (x <= -0.25) {
                return a3 - b3*x - c3*x*x - d3*x*x*x - e3*x*x*x*x;
            }
            return a4 - b4*x - c4*x*x - d4*x*x*x + e4*x*x*x*x;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (x <= 0.5) {
            if (x <= 0.25) {
                return a5 + b5*x - c5*x*x + d5*x*x*x + e5*x*x*x*x;
            }
            return a6 + b6*x - c6*x*x + d6*x*x*x - e6*x*x*x*x;
        }
        else {
            if (x <= 0.75) {
                return a7 - b7*x - c7*x*x + d7*x*x*x - e7*x*x*x*x;
            }
            else if (x <= 1.0) {
                return a8 - b8*x + c8*x*x - d8*x*x*x + e8*x*x*x*x;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0.0;
}
```

I tested this by calling the original version (`op1`) and my version (`op2`) both inside the same loop with the same random input in the range [-1.0, 1.0]. Both functions return the same value. Profiling the code over a hundred million iterations of the loop, I got the following results:

[image: profiling results]

So, the `op2` version is a little less than twice as fast as the original.

---

**Update:**

I also tested a version that maps the input to an integer and then switches on that. That only works because the intervals are all the same size, so whereas the approach in `op2` could work for arbitrary intervals, this one won't. To do the mapping I add 1 to the input, to shift the input range to [0, 2.0], and then multiply by 4, to expand the range to [0, 8.0]. Then I convert it to `int` so that we can switch on it. The nice thing about a `switch` statement with a number of consecutive values is that the compiler can implement it as a jump table, which makes it very fast. The cost is that extra floating point multiplication. Here's the function:

```
double op3(double x) {
    int c = (int)((x + 1) * 4);    // mapping from double to int
    switch (c) {
        case 0: {
            return a1 + b1*x + c1*x*x + d1*x*x*x + e1*x*x*x*x;
        }
        case 1: {
            return a2 + b2*x - c2*x*x - d2*x*x*x - e2*x*x*x*x;
        }
        case 2: {
            return a3 - b3*x - c3*x*x - d3*x*x*x - e3*x*x*x*x;
        }
        case 3: {
            return a4 - b4*x - c4*x*x - d4*x*x*x + e4*x*x*x*x;
        }
        case 4: {
            return a5 + b5*x - c5*x*x + d5*x*x*x + e5*x*x*x*x;
        }
        case 5: {
            return a6 + b6*x - c6*x*x + d6*x*x*x - e6*x*x*x*x;
        }
        case 6: {
            return a7 - b7*x - c7*x*x + d7*x*x*x - e7*x*x*x*x;
        }
        case 7: {
            return a8 - b8*x + c8*x*x - d8*x*x*x + e8*x*x*x*x;
         }
        default: {
            return 0.0;
        }
    }
}
```

And the results:

[image: results including the switch version]

So, `op3` is a lot faster than the original `op1`, but `op2` is still the winner in this case. If you had more cases, though, I think you'd eventually reach a point where the cost of mapping the input to an integer is less than the cost of the comparisons in `op2`.

Looking at the three functions, you can see that the complexity of the `op1` approach is O(n), where n is the number of intervals. The `op2` approach is O(log n), since there are log n levels of comparison needed for n intervals. And the `op3` approach is O(1): once you map the input to an interval, the switch statement can use a jump table to find the right case in constant time.

Comment: Just a note, implementing a binary search manually like this in the if/else rather than implementing a switch/case of an int (multiplied first by 4 then casted from x) gave a huge performance increase. I would figure that the compiler automatically makes the best search with switch case statements, but it didn’t.

Comment: Can you also benchmark against @dash-o answer variant?

Answer (score 3):

Other than the using compile flag (-Ofast on Linux/Mint19), which will speedup performance by about 2.5 (100,000,000 calls, mostly within the range), there are few minor adjustment that can help:

- Replacing if with lookups. see below. Reduce wasting time to find the right case. Coefficient has been adjusted +/- based on addition/subtraction of the formula.

This will provide +25% speed.

Original code: un-optimized:  2.154
Optimized with -Ofast: 0.678
Modified code, -Ofast: 0.581

```
double operation(double x) {
    static double aa[] = { a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8 } ;
    static double bb[] = { b1, b2, -b3, -b4, b5, b6, -b7, -b8 } ;
    static double cc[] = { c1, -c2, -c3, -c4, -c5, -c6, -c7, c8 } ;
    static double dd[] = { d1, -d2, -d3, -d4, d5, d6, d7, -d8 } ;
    static double ee[] = { e1, -e2, -e3, e4, e5, -e6, -e7, e8 } ;


    if (x < -1.0 || x > 1.0) {
        return 0 ;
    }
    int p = x*4 + 4 ;
//    if ( p < 0 ) p = 1;
    return aa[p] + bb[p]*x + cc[p]*x*x + dd[p]*x*x*x + ee[p]*x*x*x*x;
}
```

Note: I believe original code has a minor. It will use the coefficient for (x<-0.5) for any negative value <-1. I believe intention was that anything outside -1..+1 should return 0.

Comment: Instead of doing multiple arrays, you'd get better cache locality with a single cache-line aligned array of `struct {double a,b,c,d,e,pad [3];}` so all of the constants for a given range end up in the same cache line... Of course we wouldn't need multuple ranges if Remez vs Taylor series were used:  Vurtun/nuklear has an example for its internal trig functions.

Comment: That's a good idea. I tried to use the above structure, together with the vectoriziation built-ins - to get the mm256_* to do the work - hopefully using verctor multiplication + horizontal add. I was not able to get the right result (or the speedup) - I have some assembly experience, but no practical experience with AVX/SSE builtin. Hope someone can continue from here.

Comment: Just fixed the code to get the right numbers. The modified structure perform 5% slower vs the solution above. Not sure how. I will leave it to someone with more experience in vectorize operation then myself

Comment: With AVX, gcc -Ofast -mavx512f - 4X speedup

Comment: I get "illegal instruction: 4" when using -mavx512f on OSX here. Seems like double op2(double x) listed below still outperforms this one. I also implemented as per Scott Hunter's suggestion which gives a performance boost: (((ee[p]*x+dd[p])*x+cc[p])*x+bb[p])*x+aa[p]

Comment: You're right about the range needing to be restricted to -1 to 1, but for quick testing I restricted it in my inputs to -1 to 1.

Comment: Still leaves me with the question why manually implemented if/else binary search per Caleb's answer seems to work faster than lookup table or switch.

Comment: Sequential execution of calls (e,g, -1 to +1, step 0.00001) will make branch prediction very easy, eliminating/reducing the cost of the binary search. Try with values that will fall into different bucket on every call.

Comment: For the -mavx512, you will need a machine with latest AVX support. The illegal instruction indicate your host does not have one. I'm still working to get this executed for me

Comment: @JohnErnest please ignore my comment about -mavx512f. I'm measured it on online VM, but I'm not able to replicate the result. The assembly was showing madd (multiple/add) instructions, which I thought would speed up execution. Need more investigation. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

using clang on a vanilla mac:

```
double dcos(double a, double b, double c, double d, double e, double x) {
        return a + b * x + c * x * x + d * x * x * x + e * x * x * x * x;
}
```

generated 10 mulsd, 4 addsd
whereas:

```
double dcos(double a, double b, double c, double d, double e, double x) {
        double x2 = x * x;
        return a + b * x + c * x2 + d * x * x2 + e * x2 * x2;
}
```

generated 7 mulsd, 3 addsd.
It may be a little less numerically stable, but that is a difference.  In a Quick and dirty test, it shaved about 16% off.

```
bfm:tmp steve$ cc -O3 m.c m2.c -o m2
bfm:tmp steve$ cc -O3 m.c m1.c -o m1
bfm:tmp steve$ time ./m1
inf

real    0m4.136s
user    0m4.100s
sys 0m0.026s
bfm:tmp steve$ time ./m2
inf

real    0m3.501s
user    0m3.475s
sys 0m0.023s
```

Comment: What compilation/optimization flags did you use? (https://godbolt.org/z/Sg95j-)

Comment: -O3; nothing fancy.  With -cl-fast-relaxed-math, they were identical, and faster again at 5 multiplies

Comment: If you have a reasonably modern processor, you have fused-multiply-add instructions. Try again with `-mfma`. Horner's rule makes your answer wrong.

Comment: This seems to be a case of 'pocket' optimization.  I.E. optimization too early.  usually such optimizations are not worth the effort.  Suggest finishing the program, so it correctly works, then tracing the program to see where the bottle necks are.  However, usually the best optimization is a careful evaluation of the overall algorithm as you look for bottle necks in the algorithm

Comment: I tried this initially and didn’t get the performance increase I was looking for, but @Scott Hunter’s factorization method and also the binary search for if/else gave the biggest performance increase other than compiler optimization flags.